# Prevent Angular Material autocomplete overflowing page container

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

Using Material with Angular 8, autocomplete panel spills outside the page when the options are long - I expected the panel would be repositioned to ensure it remained entirely inside the viewport.

Autocomplete options come from an API response, implementation of the autocomplete is bog-standard, using the default CDK overlay to render the panel. `panelWidth` is `fit`, which explains the wide panel (growing to fit options).

How can I ensure the options are positioned inside the viewport?

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">                                
    <input matInput
        [formControlName]="controlName"
        [matAutocomplete]="autoCompleteCode" /> 
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption panelWidth="fit" #autoCompleteCode="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
            {{ option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]